# Sharing a taxonomy between two post types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have two custom post types, genres and movies.  I'd like to list the genres with checkboxes next to them, and when submitted, I'd like to list the movies tagged with genres previously selected, so genres can belong to multiple movies and vise verse.  I'm unsure if this is something I could accomplish with custom fields, or if I should consolidate both post types into one?  There doesn't seem to be a method of sharing a taxonomy between two post types, at least that I could find.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Prepare an array of genres, when form gets submitted. And then use this array to retrieve custom post type movies that's having tag as genres name using get_term_by function. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/exclude-posts-containing-a-particular-tag

Comment: Thanks I think I got it, just having a bit of difficulty actually comparing the returned array to stored terms of the custom post type -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022730/storing-terms-in-post-array-and-returning-corresponding-posts-on-form-submit